# How to get unconfirmed-transactions count by API

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, api

[This site](https://blockchain.info/ja/unconfirmed-transactions) shows counts of unconfirmed transactions.

And there is a API that returns in `json` format.

https://blockchain.info/ja/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json

But I couldn't find the count in the `json`.

How can I get the count by using this API?

Comment: Their server don't return the count. You can get the count by executing 'javascript:console.log(count);' in the URL bar when you are in https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

Comment: If you want their mempool count: https://blockchain.info/q/unconfirmedcount  
 However, I'm not sure why their mempool transaction count is different than their "unconfirmed transaction count"